# how linux preempt in IRQ?

Tags: linux, interrupt, schedule, preemption

I don't understand how the preempt work on interrupt exit path.

the source code is under linux/v5.11.14/source/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S

```
__irq_svc:
    svc_entry
    irq_handler

#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPTION
    ldr r8, [tsk, #TI_PREEMPT]      @ get preempt count
    ldr r0, [tsk, #TI_FLAGS]        @ get flags
    teq r8, #0              @ if preempt count != 0
    movne   r0, #0              @ force flags to 0
    tst r0, #_TIF_NEED_RESCHED
    blne    svc_preempt
#endif

    svc_exit r5, irq = 1            @ return from exception
 UNWIND(.fnend      )
ENDPROC(__irq_svc)
```

after call *svc_preempt*, the scheduler will switch to another task. like this:
(taskA interrupted by irq,  then preempt from irq to taskB).
[irq preempt call path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds9Ej.png)

my question is:

1. when next schedule, it's direct switch back to taskA or back to *svc_exit*?
2. if switch back to *svc_exit*, the context of svc_exit will be overwrite when another irq raise. if switch back to taskA, but we come from IRQ, when switch to taskB we didn't save context of taskA.

thanks.